# Did my php form get hacked?

Tags: php, forms

I have a php form on my site. I got a strange submission earlier today which looked like this:

```
Name: nxrjpsm
Email: zdphfr@nhrvvz.com
Address: HEnMURocqvvkaPfc
Venue: JLmFlwzOrSP
Day/Time: 12
Comments: xmUHQr  <a ="http://jhigpiylmxmk.com/">jhigpiylmxmk</a>, [url=http://zbuzlrdkhaea.com/]zbuzlrdkhaea[/url], [link=http://oqcraysadabl.com/]oqcraysadabl[/link], http://eprpuivhmkwg.com/
```

Now my php form doesn't seem to be working. 
I have not been getting any emails from the submissions.

I have form validation and stuff built into the form but its probably vulnerable in some way.

Could it have been hacked?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps it would be more appropriate for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not exactly about programming. Moreover, the question doesn't have any code to even identify if there is a vulnerability issue.

Comment: it is about programming. it relates to a php form. I wanted to know whether the submission I got was gibberish or malicious. I wasn't asking for your criticism

Answer (score 1):

From the data that you have specified in your question
it looks like you got spam data which happens because of Internet bots
so I recommend you to use validation in your website like captcha or you can ask question to user which a internet bot can not answer.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Bot can hack simply form with classic types of validation. I think you should insert a captcha code to your form. N.B: some types of simple captchas are hacked from advanced bot